# Why can't I get a credential manager to save my password in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, credentials, tortoisegit

TortoiseGit keeps asking for my password when I interact with a remote.

I've just (re-)installed Git v2.7.4 and TortoiseGit v2.0 but when I go to credential manager and set these settings as most of the advice I've read suggests:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong / how can I get this up and running?

**Edit** - I checked and .gitconfig is writeable and looks like this:

```
[user]
    email = jonc@mydomain.com
    name = Jon Cage
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\jonc\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
[credential]
[credential]
[credential]
[credential]
[credential]
[credential]
    helper = wincred
```

Comment: There was a bug in TortoiseGit 2.0 which broke the selection of the credential helper.

Comment: @MrTux: Do you have a link? I can't find it in their issue tracker.. https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues

Comment: There is no issue tracker entry, its only fixed in code: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/commit/c6f0a57d9bcee7fc0e727462ba7ead8f82cec4c2

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in TortoiseGit 2.0.

[TortoiseGit 2.1](https://tortoisegit.org/download) was just released where this issue [is fixed](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/releasenotes/#Release_2.1.0.0).

> **== Bug Fixes ==**
>   * Fix the the credential helper settings dialog

Answer (score 0):

Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000173/tortoisegit-save-user-authentication-credentials) will help. There are multiple approaches (winstore, _netrc file, using Advanced on Git > Credential) - use whatever is working for you, since in Git philosophy there is more than one way to do it.