# TortoiseGit: How to logout?

Tags: git, gitlab, tortoisegit

I checked out a project from gitlab using username A.(with tortoisegit) Now I'd like to check out an other project from Gitlab with user B. Unfortunately tortoisegit doesn`t ask for my crendentials and just tries to check out with user A. How can I logout user a for my local tortoisegit client?

Comment: This is a highly irregular scenario. You would be better off to give ONE of your userids access to both projects from the Gitlab Admin page, and just stay logged in as that one user.

Comment: Ok, then I'd like to give user B the permission. But tortoisegit still tries to login with user A.

Comment: You only have one windows login at one time. That windows login should have one global GIt configured account.  You are already in the failure state.

Comment: which remote protocol do you use, is it http(s)?

Comment: check answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14000173/2303202

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it manually refer https://codeyarns.com/2012/12/04/how-to-set-user-name-and-email-in-tortoisegit/ or use command line git config --user.email "Xyz@xyz.com"

Comment: This is possible, but not a great idea.

Comment: I tried changing the username but it still doesn't work

Comment: this is authoring information to be written to commit, it's unrelated to remote authentication