# TortoiseGit doesn't add files automatically

Tags: git, gitlab, tortoisegit

When I create a new file in a git tracked folder and click `commit` it doesn't show for commit. If I want to show it, I need to right click, then click `Add ...` then to commit it. Other users can commit without the `Add` step. I am master of the project in GitLab.

Other problem is when I want to push every time TortoiseGit requires me to re-enter username and password, but when someone else (my friend) try to do that, it doesn't request his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a rule in your .gitignore file that might be excluding files unexpectedly. For example here I have localhost.pfx set to be ignored but the right-click context menu still allows me to add it to a commit:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Make sure the `Show Unversioned Files` is checked. See:

[image]

For your second problem, go `Settings/Git/Credential` and try to use `manager` helper. Also see [A: TortoiseGit save user authentication / credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351702/3247152)

Answer (score 2):

On similar issue:

I wanted the Windows Explorer to show git folder as changed (red color) when a new file is added.

Below worked:

```
> Tortoise > Settings > Icon Overlays
  > check the box "Unversioned files mark parent folder as modified"
  > Apply & OK
> Restart computer (since it is explorer extension it is not working without restart)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Under the settings for TortoiseGit, there is an option on the `Dialog 2` tab for `Select Items Automatically`

To remember your password, you'll need to save your credentials. See the credentials tab of the settings. Depending on which one you have installed, you can select the appropriate credential helper.

See the [TortoiseGit Settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html) doc for details.

On a side note, having to manually add your files for commit is usually not a bad thing, there are many scenarios where it is advantageous to thoughtfully craft a commit over just adding all the changes in your working directory brute force.

Comment: TortoiseGit -> Setting -> Dialogs 2 "Select items automatically" is already cheked ..

Comment: @Morgan Do modified files show up in the commit window?

Comment: @Morgan are there any tracked files in the folder with the untracked file? Git will only show the lowest untracked item. If I add the file `untrackedpath/file.txt` to my filesystem, git will only show me `untrackedpath/` as untracked in the status.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your `.gitignore` file to have a clean start or edit it if you see what is wrong with it. In my case, I don't know why, I had a *, so everything was being ignored, I just removed it and everything worked fine again.