# Bypass .net framework requirement for git-bash / git for windows

Tags: git-bash, git-for-windows

### .Net Framework requirement / git credential manager core

I have been given a virtual workstation that has quite a few restrictions.
Among them, I see that I am unable to install the .net framework 4.7.2  - which is a requirement apparently of the git-credential-manager-core.exe.

[image]

Without the credential manager, I cannot save my username/password.

### Attempt to install .net framework

I tried installing the .net framework but it just gets stuck in an infinite loop.
I started the installation service but nothing works.

[image]

I also tried the development bundle but this also fails ( ndp472-devpack-enu.exe ).
[image]

I checked the log and I see the following:

```
[4674:9F48][2023-04-01T10:34:10]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Process returned error: 0x13ec
[4674:9F48][2023-04-01T10:34:10]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to execute EXE package.
[5784:6C74][2023-04-01T10:34:10]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[5784:6C74][2023-04-01T10:34:10]i319: Applied execute package: netfxfullrefreshisv, result: 0x800713ec, restart: None
[5784:6C74][2023-04-01T10:34:10]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to execute EXE package.
```

I search for this error and saw some people mentioned space. However, I have 16 GB frree on the hard drive so I don't think this is the issue.

In the end (due to time restrictions), I have assumed it is a security issue and am looking for a work-around. I also tried to see the event-viewer but I just see some information events.

### Questions

1. Any ideas how to use tortoise git without the credential manager?
2. Also any ideas how to use the newest version?
3. Is it possible to replace the new git-credential manager with the old one?

Comment: This is not TortoiseGit, TortoiseGit does not require .Net.

Comment: @MrTux It's git bash/git-for-windows right? I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: You don't have to use git-credential-manager. There are alternative ways on how to store credentials (e.g., the "very old way": using %HOME%\_netrc: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6031214/3906760). or use ssh keys. You could also try to extract git-credential/winstore or what you used from the very old git distribution (i suppose it's just one executable that is configured as credentiual helper). More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351702/3906760

Comment: @MrTux that's the answer I was looking for. Care to post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use git-credential-manager.

There are alternative ways on how to store credentials (e.g., the "very old way": using `%HOME%\_netrc`: [Git - How to use .netrc file on Windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6031214/3906760)). or use ssh keys.

You could also try to extract git-credential/winstore or what you used from the very old git distribution (i suppose it's just one executable that is configured as credentiual helper). More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351702/3906760