# TortoiseGit keeps asking for SSH passphrase

Tags: tortoisegit, pageant

I have seen a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314232/tortoisesvn-and-putty-keeps-asking-for-passphrase) about this issue but I have not got things to work.

I have **TortoiseGit** installed on a new PC.

It is setup to use `TortoisePlink.exe` and I have the correct public/private keys setup on my computer and with **BitBucket**.

I can **push** content w/o problems to the remote server but I keep getting a popup window from Pageant asking for my **passphrase**.

[image: Passphrase request]

Please note that it is the *first time* I do a **push** after switching on the computer. Once it has been entered, I don't have to do it again in that *Windows session*.

When my computer starts, Pageant does **NOT** start. If I manually start Pageant there is **NO** keys listed.

I thought I could suppress that?

Comment: Did you try one of those https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846972/tortoisegit-asking-password#8848529

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks for that. Why should I need to change it to `ssh.exe` though? I thought the setup I have should work.

Comment: It seems that `ssh.exe` can remember the password(you just have to enter the password for the first time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yor SSH key is encrypted, and thus, it needs to be decrypted for usage. This can either be done for

- every connection by putty, plink or tortoise(git)plink,
- every Pageant session (pageant caches the unencrypted key in memory, so that you don't need to re-enter it again and again),
- ever, by using PuttyGen and storing the ssh key unencrypted (then, however, if it gets stolen, an attacker can directly use it).

(Based on my answer on the TortoiseGit issue tracker https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/3004#note_33383409)