# How to solve TortoiseGit - git CLI stdin wrapper (Error)?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When I set up TortoiseGit on my machine I didn't give it a password. But when  using it to run `git.exe push --recurse-submodules=on-demand --progress "origin" feature/myatthiha-OJT` it's requesting a password.

[image: This is my error.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tortoisegit asking password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846972/tortoisegit-asking-password)

Comment: thz for answering sir!.But it still have that error(asking password).

Comment: Which solution did you try from the link that @Peter sent? There were a number of answers to that question. It does look like a very similar one to the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

In general there are two options to authenticate to a Git Server.

1) Use https URLs, then password saving is possible using a credential helper (installed by default by Git for Windows)

2) Use SSH. Here, you can authenticate using a password or a SSH key. Passwordless authentication is only possible using a SSH key.

As you have configured to use OpenSSH as ssh client you have to make sure OpenSSH knows/uses the right key (default is .confgi/id_rsa; cf. [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3225862/3906760)).

If you want to use PuTTY you have to change the ssh client to tortoisegitplink (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-network and https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that you found most helpful.