# Composer permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, composer-php, bitbucket

I Have a private repo on BitBucket, Im trying to install on localhost using composer install, here is my composer.json file:

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git"
    }
]
}
```

When I run composer install from the command line I get:

> [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to execute git clone --mirror "git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git" "C:/Users/...../"
>     Cloning into bare repository 'C:/Users/.....'...
>     Permission denied (publickey).
>     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>     Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>     and the repository exists.

My key pair has an passphrase but composer never asks for it, I am running windows 10 with the Pageant client running and the correct key selected.

Also there is a config file with this data:

```
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/openssh (yes my key name is openssh)
```

The funny thing is that if I copy and paste this command:

> git clone --mirror "git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git"

I do get ask for my passphrase and after that it start cloning the Repo.

What could be wrong? most information about this error refers directly for git commands, but in my case they work, what is not working is composer, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: this my comment might be a little asidetopic, therefore as a comment, I solved composer public key issue by running composer inside my docker, as probably on my PC I had an older version of git than inside the docker - stackoverflow.com/questions/48946855/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and answer from this post helped me
[Why git can't remember my passphrase under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356869/3156855)

All I did was to run 'start-ssh-agent' in CMD and provide password.

> Third solution Assumes Window, msysgit, and native command prompt.
>
> Install msysgit
>
> Make sure to allow git to be used on the MS-DOS
>
> command prompt Run start-ssh-agent
>
> Enter SSH passphrases
>
> All done! Git
> commands should now work in the native command prompt.

Comment: HOLY CRAP!!! I literally spent 4 hours trawling through forums wondering if this was git if it was phpstorm if it was composer or what?! This worked no problem I am so happy!

Comment: Same here, three hours of banging the head against the wall! I'd put 10 votes if I could, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. Make sure your public key is loaded into Bitbucket Cloud

1. Open a browser and log into Bitbucket Cloud.
2. Choose Username > Manage Account from the menu bar. The system displays the Account settings page.
3. Click SSH keys. The SSH Keys page displays. It shows a list of any existing keys.
4. If your key is not listed set one up.

#### 2. Make sure your identity is loaded into your SSH Agent

Open Pageant to view loaded keys. If your key is not in the list click `Add Key`.

#### You can test which key you are sending

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

Comment: Update: (Avatar) > **Personal settings** > SSH keys. The keys are no longer under Manage account. [Instructions for setting up a key.](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/)

Answer (score 0):

Having faced the same issue as described by OP, I too tried to follow the instructions on [Why git can't remember my passphrase under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370030/why-git-cant-remember-my-passphrase-under-windows/4356869#4356869)

But I limited my steps to these:

1. Run PuTTY's pageant.exe, open your .ppk file ("Add Key"), and
   provide your passphrase for your key.
2. Access Windows' environment
   variables dialog (Right-click on "Computer", Click on "Properties",
   Click on "Advanced system settings" or the "Advanced" tab, click on
   "Environment Variables"). Add the following environment variable:

   GIT_SSH=C:\full\path\to\plink.exe

After the restarting the command line tool (important to have the new env variables take effect) it worked.