# bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to perform 
git clone from bitbucket.org

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:mascai/regru_junjob.git
```

Received error:

> Cloning into 'regru_junjob'...
>   Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '2406:da00:ff00::34cc:ea4a' to the list of known hosts.
>
> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I add pub and private keys to my server:

```
~/.ssh# ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts  reg_jj  reg_jj.pub
```

Added pub key to the bitbucket.org
https://bitbucket.org/mascai/regru_junjob/admin/access-keys/

**What is the reason of the error?**

May be usefull

```
~# ls -la ~/.ssh/
total 28
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 ноя 13 15:26 .
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 ноя 13 15:26 ..
-rw------- 1 root root  782 ноя 13 14:26 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  381 ноя 13 15:25 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3978 ноя 13 15:35 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1679 ноя 13 15:26 reg_jj
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  391 ноя 13 14:54 reg_jj.pub
```

Comment: Did you set wrong file permissions for `~/.ssh/`?
Let us see the result of `ls -la ~/.ssh/`, if you feel free to share it.

Comment: Have you used the Key "id_rsa.pub"? That key is used for default auth.

Comment: Added id_rsa.pub but received error again. Are .ssh permissions OK?

Comment: In case if you have multiple ssh keys, you need to setup them in this way - https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/. Read it carefully, do setup, and do not forget to change git clone address according to aliases in config file.

Comment: [`ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34894219/7976758)

Comment: Your permissions are incorrect on `reg_jj` - while 0644 is fine for the .pub files, the private key (the one without the `.pub`) needs to be set to 0600. You should also check that your SSH client is using the appropriate key, but @phd's answer should cover that.

Answer (score 2):

Using the command `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` suggested by @phd, I was able to figure out the issue. It was indeed, a permissions issue

```
Permissions 0664 for '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

**ssh-keygen -t rsa** "To generate the SSH"

Next it will ask for the folder to create the SSH(you can press enter to create it in default folder )

press enter to confirm the folder

now you have generated the SSH Successfully

please type below command the copy the Generated SSH

**cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**

now you can open your BitBucket Account and personal settings -> Security -> SSH then paste the SSH key you copied. you can give any name in the label field