# Remember GPG password when signing git commits

Tags: git, shell, gnupg

Would it be possible for the GPG password to be saved, so that I am not prompted for the passphrase everytime I make a git commit?

Comment: Look into the `gpg-agent` perhaps?

Comment: Just for completeness, this was also asked on SU https://superuser.com/questions/624343/keep-gnupg-credentials-cached-for-entire-user-session

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can set a timeout period for gpg-agent in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` with this line:

```
default-cache-ttl 3600
```

That would tell gpg-agent to store the passphrase for one hour.  You wouldn't want it to be indefinite, but not constantly typing it is of benefit too.

Comment: 
More info » https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Agent-Options.html

Comment: I do not have a ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf file, just a ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf. What should I do?

Comment: Make a text file with that line in it, though if you're still using GPG 1.4 it won't use gpg-agent. Most people use 2.0 or 2.1 these days except on systems that need 1.4 for some reason (usually headless systems like routers).

Comment: do you need to restart the `gpg-agent` for this to take effect (particularly, when you had to create the conf file)?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but you can if you want to and it certainly won't hurt. The best way to do that is run `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` and the agent will restart (for that user) with the next gpg process or command invoked, regardless of whether or not it requires the passphrase or pinentry.

Comment: This either doesn't work anymore in gpg@2.2.20 or it doesn't accept large values like `1209600` (2 weeks).

Comment: [I posted a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788805/cache-gpg-passphrase-for-git-signing-on-mac), in case the issue is specific to v2 of GnuPG or my environment (macOS).

Comment: I would suggest that two weeks would be a bit long anyway; what happens if your laptop gets stolen? I have set mine to cache for 12 hours max.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg 1 week (604800) seems to work on gpg@2.2.29, if that's helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 19):

If you are on Mac, I would suggest that you use `pinentry-mac`. Then you can save the password to the macOS keychain.

Install with `brew install pinentry-mac`, and then add this line `pinentry-program /opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` (remove/comment out any other `pinentry-program` line in that file)

Comment: After this configuration change, you might need to restart the gpg-agent with `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`.