# Cache GPG passphrase for git signing on Mac

Tags: git, gnupg, gpg-agent

There is already a more generic thread on the topic, [Remember GPG password when signing git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847431/remember-gpg-password-when-signing-git-commits), but the answer there doesn't work for me. My environment is:

- Mac (macOS@10.15.7)
- Bash (the default that comes with macOS)
- Git v2.27.0
- GnuPG v2.2.20 (libgcrypt 1.8.5)

I installed GnuPG via Homebrew and wrote the following settings into the `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file:

```
default-cache-ttl 1209600 # 14 days
max-cache-ttl 31536000 # 1 year
```

But the cache isn't applied. Every ten minutes or so after I do a `git commit`, gpg prompts me to input the password again.

This is my global `.gitignore` file:

```
[commit]
    gpgSign = true
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It will only save the passphrase as long as `gpg-agent` is running. If you don't want to type it in after the agent has been stopped, don't use a passphrase.

Comment: Thanks @dan1st - do you know how can I make `gpg-agent` start along with the Bash session?

Comment: Add it to the `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my personal setup I have added the signingkey to the user section.

```
[user]
name = "Marco Franssen"
email = "marco@my-email.com"
signingkey = 63B0C3B53E26....

[commit]
gpgSign = true
```

Furthermore I have the following plugins in oh-my-zsh. (`~/.zshrc`)

```
plugins=(git keychain gpg-agent)

zstyle :omz:plugins:keychain agents ssh,gpg
zstyle :omz:plugins:keychain identities id_rsa 63B0C3B53E2....
```

This plugin boots an agent for my ssh and gpg keys.

Furthermore I have added the following file

```sh
$ cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
default-cache-ttl 3600
```

For Bash you might add the following to your `~/.bashrc`.

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/gpg-agent/gpg-agent.plugin.zsh

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Marco! I updated the question body to specify what shell I'm using. Do you know what would be the equivalent for `plugins=(git keychain gpg-agent)` in Bash?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I have updated with a link the the script that the plugin adds. You should be able to add that to your ~/.bashrc.