# Get Visual Studio 2017 to work with ssh-agent / ssh-add for git

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I "synchronize" (pull, push) my repository in Visual Studio, I notice the `git-askpass.exe` window pop up and ask me for my ssh private key passphrase for my git repository. That's fine, but I was wondering whether there is a way to get it to work with `ssh-agent.exe`.

When starting my git bash interpreter, I always also start its own `ssh-agent.exe` (it's in `Program Files/git` as opposed to Visual Studio's `Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core`) and `ssh-add.exe` my private key so that it asks me once for passphrase and then stops bothering me. From Visual Studio I always have to reenter the passphrase for my private key upon "sync-ing" the projects. Is there any way to slipstream this?

I was thinking of deleting that whole Visual Studio folder and creating a hard link towards the Git for Windows folder...

There's also [Connect to Git repository with SSH using Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773636/connect-to-git-repository-with-ssh-using-visual-studio-2017/43533356) which doesn't feel like it covers my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I think i figured this one out.

Visual Studio 2017 launches git from
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd` and `git.exe` from there attempts its own auth methods until one works.

The auth method I care about in my question deals with the already running `ssh-agent` process. Upon launching it, `ssh-agent` detects its environment and "conveniently" advises upon which "standard" env variables to set, such as:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-iTGtZyR9tAxO/agent.12088; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=972; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
#echo Agent pid 972;
```

Notice that the path is in "MINGW-speak", resolving to paths such as `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp`. It's actually OK, even outside of `git bash` to refer to paths like that (`git.exe`, `ssh-agent.exe` will be able to resolve them).

So I have 2 scripts, one that loads my private key, which is started by my `.bashrc` the first time I open a `git bash`:

`10_ssh.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment

function start_agent {
    echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."

    # run it with eval so that it sticks after terminal completion
    eval "/usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > ${SSH_ENV}"

    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 ${SSH_ENV}
    . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null

    /usr/bin/ssh-add;
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

and a new one I just created, that also puts into "Windows" those variables:

`15_ssh_windows_hacks.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This one makes sure that the Windows environment recognizes the ssh agent started before

if [[ `uname` == MINGW* ]]
then
    setx SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > /dev/null
    setx SSH_AGENT_PID $SSH_AGENT_PID > /dev/null
fi
```

The only caveat is that Visual Studio has to be started **after** executing this script, because apparently it only reads its `ENV` once when it starts, and not every time it spawns the child `git.exe` process.

Comment: I combined the 2 scripts into one. That way I can just launch it independently from .bashrc or .bash_profile. Reason for combining the 2: The first script does not create permanent environment variables if not launched from .bashrc.

Comment: @DanielHillebrand I'm using these scripts on both Linux and Windows, that's why I'm keeping them separated.

Comment: That makes perfectly sense for your use-case. In my case I am only using Windows at the moment and I lost quite some time analysing error messages and trying to get .bashrc executing the first script. Merging the 2 scripts works best in my case. Thanks a lot for this resource!

Comment: I also added something to help with `ssh-agent` in the PowerShell world - https://github.com/foxx1337/psprofile.

Comment: For me it didn't work with `if [[ `uname` == MINGW* ]]` condition, because I was starting
bash from: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.
In my case uname returned: `MSYS...`

Comment: Could you explain what the problems were and what your script does to fix it? you give the environment variables but don't ever say what's wrong with them, you make a "tongue in cheek" comment about them but don't explain. You even say "its actually OK" which makes me think these are acceptable?