# Authentication required for GIT credentials in Visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, credentials

I am pretty new here and I am trying to push some files in Git hub using Visual studio terminal, but every time I do this, I have to put my credentials. Since today I cannot type my password into the terminal and I am having a hard time with this:(.
Can anyone let me know how can I solve this?

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/about-ssh for authentication without a username/password

Comment: Check out this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773636/connect-to-git-repository-with-ssh-using-visual-studio-2017