# How do I connect Visual Studio 2017 to BitBucket in 2022?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, bitbucket, ssh-keys, team-explorer

I use Visual Studio 2017 to connect to BitBucket.  VS has been set up by IT for years.  All I do is push/pull/fetch from inside Visual Studio.  Today, I started getting errors.  I remember seeing something about BitBucket not accepting passwords anymore.  I've been Googling all morning, but can't get it to work.  I've tried setting up an App Password and using it to login, but that password isn't accepted.  I tried downloading a new version of Bitbucket Extension to VS, but that also won't take my login.  I've found some mentions of ssh keys if I was using Git Bash, but I'm not sure how that relates to VS.  Can someone walk me through getting VS setup to work with Bitbucket again?

Here's the error I get when I try to push my changes to BitBucket in VS:

```
Opening repositories:
C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\nfsshopfloor
Error: cannot spawn /C/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual     Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
could not read Password for 'https://xxxx@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled
```

Pushing to https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git

Here's where I'm clicking Push inside VS:
[image]

Here's what I see under the Connect option in VS after I installed the Bitbucket Extension:
[image]

When I click in login, I see the following screen when I try to login using my Bitbucket login.  I've tried both my regular Bitbucket password and a new app password I created.

[image]

Comment: Best solution is switch to SSH public/private key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Invalid credentials problem in bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378839/how-to-solve-invalid-credentials-problem-in-bitbucket)

Comment: I've created a SSH public/private key, but I need to know how to get that to work with Visual Studio.  When I try to set up the Bitbucket Extension, it asks for a login and password.  I see nothing in VS about adding an SSH key.  Can someone show me how to set up VS to work with Bitbucket under this new system?

Comment: Okay, how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773636/connect-to-git-repository-with-ssh-using-visual-studio-2017

Comment: @matt That's the same article I found, but couldn't get it to work.  I followed everything, but when I select push in VS, it gives errors saying that no connection is set up.