# How do I add a password to an OpenSSH private key that was generated without a password?

Tags: ssh

I generated an OpenSSH private key using PuTTYgen (and exported it in OpenSSH format).

How can I put a password on this existing key (I know how to generate a new key with a password)?

Comment: If you see this comment, please mark one of the answers as accepted or write a comment saying what they missed. Thanks!

Comment: Add is the same as change or remove: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke , possible same for change: http://serverfault.com/questions/50775/how-do-i-change-my-private-key-passphrase

Comment: If you get ***`Bad passphrase`*** on an `id_ed25519` key but the password is correct, then you are probably using a down-level `ssh-keygen` to manage it.

Answer (score 491):

Try the following command:

```bash
ssh-keygen -p -f keyfile
```

From the ssh-keygen man page

```
 -p      Requests changing the passphrase of a private key file instead of
         creating a new private key.  The program will prompt for the file
         containing the private key, for the old passphrase, and twice for
         the new passphrase.

 -f filename
         Specifies the filename of the key file.
```

**Example**:

```bash
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: For those wanting to know what -f is: It specifies the input file.

Comment: // , @sigjuice, would you please post an example, like `$ ssh-keygen -p -f /Users/sigjuice/.ssh/id_rsa`? This might help people who don't know how to tell the difference between a public and a private key, and help them get their feet wet faster.

Comment: For some reason, on MacOS 10.14, this does not format the file with the `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED` header, which is incompatible with some applications checking for a passphrase. After trying several ways to get it to work, the easiest way to workaround it was just do this same thing inside a Docker container running Ubuntu and then copying the key back to my Mac.

Comment: I can still read my ssh private keys in clear text without entering any password, so I guess the above command is not enough!? (I don't want hackers to be able to read my private keys without knowing an extra password)

Comment: @mcExchange : if you did it correctly: the file should now have, under the "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" line, 2 lines indicating: the passphrase type, and the (encrypted) passphrase, then a blank line, and then the (ENCRYPTED) private key. The latest is unusable unless someone successfully decrypted it by knowing the passphrase. ie, 1) you need to enter the passphrase when asked, and only then can 2) the private key be used.  (with NO passphrase (ex: you entered twice Return when prompted), there is only the UNENCRYPTED private key (without the first 3 lines), and it *IS* usable directly)

Answer (score 46):

Use the -p option to ssh-keygen.  This allows you to change the password rather than generate a new key.

Change the password as sigjuice shows:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The required password will be the new password. (This assumes you have added the public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your authorized_keys files.) Test with ssh:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa localhost
```

You can have multiple keys with different names for different uses.

Comment: // , Would you please show an example, and how to check that the option has worked, @BillThor?

Comment: I do not understand. The passphrase is set, I see when I try to change it again. But when I try to login to remote server it doesn't ask for this passphrase password, why?

Comment: It's fine. It asks once per session :) Didn't know that.

Comment: Does this mean you have to log out and in again? Closing the terminal window and re-opening it does not work for me.

Comment: You can type `ssh-add -D` to remove your cached identity.  Then, try connecting again and it will ask you for your password.  Use `ssh-add -l` to see a list of your cached identities.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `openssl`:

```
openssl rsa -aes256 -in ~/.ssh/your_key -out ~/.ssh/your_key.enc
mv ~/.ssh/your_key.enc ~/.ssh/your_key
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/your_key
```

see: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/59164/194668

Comment: I think I'll take the _ssh-keygen_ way ;)

Comment: Thanks for providing an openssl alternative to do the task.

Comment: I'd prefer openssl. ssh-keygen did some weird stuff with the encoding which made the key unusable

Answer (score -1):

Because you've mentioned "PuTTYgen" and maybe you're using Windows , I'll direct you to the documentation for "PuTTYgen".

Go here [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-conversions] for "importing" and "exporting" a SSH private key.  These are different to using "Load" and "Save" as those options are for loading and saving a Putty specific key file.

And here [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-passphrase] for changing the passphrase.  Same thing you'd do when creating a passphrase for a new private key.

So steps are "import" the SSH key, you don't get asked for a passphrase because you didn't create one.  Then change (set) the passphrase and confirm.  Then "export" back out to the original private key file.

Hope that helps anyone else wanting to use "PuTTYgen" instead of "ssh-keygen".