# Android key hash generation for Facebook SDK using OpenSSL was not set to android when prompted

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, hash, key

I have a problem with the password generated using the following method

> First open a terminal (open a command prompt in windows).
>      Navigate in the terminal to the directory where your Android debug.keystore is stored.
>      Mostly it will located under “/Users/user_name/.android/” (In Windows will be C:\Documents and Settings.android).
>
> Once you are in the “.android” directory, run the following command.
>
> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
>
> When it prompts you for a password, type android and hit Enter
>
> Copy the value printed in the terminal that ends with an “=” and paste it in the Key Hash field in Facebook. Then click the Save Changes button.

When I was generating the key I entered my own password instead of using "android". I was wondering if there is an easy way to change the password to "android" without having to uninstall everything or something. If there is no way to modify the password, does that mean I have to generate new key? I have found something [that can be used to modify ssh keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818886/how-do-i-add-a-password-to-an-openssh-private-key-that-was-generated-without-a-p), but I am unsure how to apply it and in what file look for that key.

Comment: refer following link for key hash generation

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash

Answer (score 0):

you have put to openssl complete path which is usually inside ssl/bin. please check out ur ssl directory path

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | C:/ssl/bin/openssl sha1 -binary | C:/ssl/bin/openssl base64
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Elaborate? I want to modify the password from my own to android. That is all i want to do. Your answer has no meaning without explanation.

Comment: ur using openssl right. so u shud go up to that directory in the command. please check updated ans