# Clone, add and commit to private repository on github on macosx

Tags: git, macos, authentication, github

I am trying to clone, add some code to and commit the code to my private repository on Github. The issue is that whenever I do

```
git clone https://github.com/my-username/my-Repo.git
```

I get

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/.../my_repo.git/'
```

I didn't have this issue before executing the following command

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

Before executing above command I managed to clone the repo by using my personal access token, managed to execute `git init`, `git add blah.py` and `git push` without any issues but nothing showed up on my github page.

Now, after removing the credentials from my keychain, when I enter the CORRECT username and password when cloning my private Github repository I get the `remote: Invalid username or password.` error. I've both manually written my username and password into the terminal and copied from `saved logins` on firefox, neither works and I know the username and password is correct since I can easily login to my Github account on github.com with the same information I enter into the terminal when attempting to clone my repo. Using the e-mail does not change the "invalid ..." error.

tl;dr How do you control a private repository on macosx via terminal?

Edit: I use 2FA

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using 2FA, you actually won't use your password but instead you'll use an access token that you can create on the GitHub website.

[Here's instructions on how to do that](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).

Then for your clones / pushes / etc, use:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

More info can be seen in the answers to this [very related question].([2FA give problems when pushing to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950497/2fa-give-problems-when-pushing-to-github))

Comment: Using my token as password worked when cloning, however when I do `git push` I get no prompt about username or password, it only says that everything is up to date, which it isn't since it didn't push the change!

Comment: Did you "git add" any files you changed?

Comment: `touch blah.py` then I did `git add blah.py` then `git push` and `git commit -a -v` and finished with `git push` again. Nothing on my git page but command says everything is up to date.

Comment: Which branch are you in? What happens when you try "git push origin master"?

Comment: `git push origin master`results in `Everything up-to-date`. I am in my /Users/name/Git-Projects/my_project/. Doing `git init`results in `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/name/Git-Projects/my_project/.git/`

Comment: All the "git init" you are doing can't be good for your repo. Try doing a fresh clone from git into a different location on your local drive, then copy in and add/commit/push from there. I suspect you'll have better results.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by doing the following

```
1. signed in with my auth token
2. generating a ssh-key and adding it to my agent
3. adding the ssh-key to my github
4. cloning the repo in a different directory and skipping 'git init'
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a token, **you can enter it instead of your password** when performing Git operations over HTTPS.

For example, on the command line you would enter the following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```