# fatal Error when Pushing to remote Repository

Tags: ssh

1. i have tried all means to add this remote repository but i cant pull
   or push when i push a git-hub repository it works what am i missing

   e.gatoto@EMMANUEL MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myrepo.git (master) $ git push
   origin master e.gatoto@192.168.180.27's password: fatal:
   ''~/Desktop/myrepo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the
   repository exists.

   e.gatoto@EMMANUEL MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myrepo.git (master)

   1. 

   > **`List item`**

Answer (score 0):

If you have double authentication on github you will have to create a key when pushing from remote to get access to the repository.

You will then use the key password instead of the password to your github account.

Maybe its related?

[2FA give problems when pushing to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950497/2fa-give-problems-when-pushing-to-github)

Comment: I have already enable ssh on my server and am able to connect to my server via ssh but when i push it gives the error