# Writing a batch file that enters a password when prompted

Tags: batch-file, batching

I'm writing a batch file that runs the below command

winscp sftp://username:password@host.com:22 /privatekey=pgp530.ppk

The output is as follows

Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "username".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key".
Passphrase for key 'imported-openssh-key':

Is there any way to have the batch file enter the passphrase when prompted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a private key without a password, [or remove the password from the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-key/112409#112409)?

It'll be roughly as secure as passing in a plain-text password to the key.