# Automating a MS-DOS batch file, when password has to be entered manually

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to automate a MS-DOS command which requires a password, however the password can not be passed as one of the command line options.
How can I do this?

The command I want to run is

```
dumpdata --schema=mydb mytable C:\temp\output.sql
```

[This command extracts data from an Oracle database in the form of Insert statements]

There is then a prompt for the password, which needs to be entered manually.

Removing the password (from the database) is not an option, as per [Writing a batch file that enters a password when prompted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110894/writing-a-batch-file-that-enters-a-password-when-prompted)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you should set up an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) named `ORA_USERID` containing your username/password. If not set than you will be prompted for the password when connecting using the `dumpdata` command. Checkout [OracleTools](http://cx-oracletools.sourceforge.net/cx_OracleTools.html).

Comment: Thank you very much.  In fact (after following the instructions on the link) I simply replaced --schema=mydb with --scheme=mydb/mypassword

Comment: Yes, I found that you could achive the same thing that way too. Nice you solved it though.

Answer (score 1):

If `dumpdata` can read from a pipe, this may work:

```
echo PASSWORD | dumpdata --schema=mydb mytable C:\temp\output.sql
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this answer... It didn't work in my particular case, always good to know though!

Comment: Sure thing! Glad you found someone who was familiar with `dumpdata`!