# Authorize permanently by remote machine with SSH

Tags: https, ssh, public-key, private-key

I have remote machine which I connect with ssh like this:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key loginName@my.remote.machine.com -L 5901:localhost:5901
```

Each time I connect I receive:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/path/to/private_key':
```

I wonder how to prevent entering password each time? I.e. is that possible to permanently explain to remote machine that I am authorized user and it can trust me?

**P.S.** When I issue `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine I can see my public key content. But it looks like remote machine always ignore it or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSH key is passphrase protected. The server isn't prompting you for a password, your local machine is asking for the passphrase to use the SSH key you provided.

Information to remove the passphase can be found here: [How do I remove the passphrase for the SSH key without having to create a new key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke)

Edit: The best answer for the above question is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/965648