# Capistrano 3 deploy asking for SSH passphrase but cannot type it in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, passwords, capistrano

I'm trying to use Capistrano 3 to deploy a Rails 4 application.

```
#config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'testapp'
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:sergiotapia/testapp.git'

set :user, "deploy" # The user on the VPS server.
set :password, "hunter2$$"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/www/testapp"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :pty, true
set :format, :pretty
set :keep_releases, 1
set :rails_env, "production"
set :migrate_target, :latest

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      system "curl --silent #{fetch(:ping_url)}"
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

---

When running `cap production deploy` I get the following message:

```
DEBUG [322bb1fd]    Enter passphrase for key '/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

When I type in the terminal, I can see the characters, normally you just see whitespace when typing in passwords, right?

```
DEBUG [484154d4]    Enter passphrase for key '/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa': 
qwef

ewf
qw
ef
qwef
wqe
f
qwef
wqe
f
^Ccap aborted!
Interrupt:
```

I type in the password and press enter, and it just stays there without any new developments. I have to Ctrl + C to actually leave the terminal.

Can I set my **SSH password** in the deploy.rb file?

Comment: Am I supposed to user a password-less ssh-key for deploy servers?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

What I did was to change my configuration. In order to avoid capistrano asking for the passphrase you have to set`

```
set :pty, false
```

Then you have to generate your deploy keys in whichever computer you are using to fire the terminal (You can find a very nice guide here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git specially if you are using bitbucket) and run `cap production deploy`

The thing is that by default, capistrano will set the **forward_agent** as **true** which will use the keys generated in your computer to authenticate in the remote code repo.

Comment: would you please tell me what `passphrase` do in capistrano?

Comment: @Vinay it represents the passphrase of your key

Answer (score 0):

what I do is remove the passphrase by

Step 1: $ `ssh-keygen -p`

Step 2: $ `ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]`

Reference:

[How do I remove the passphrase for the SSH key without having to create a new key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke?rq=1)