# Capistrano rails deploy - passphrase for SSH key not authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to deploy my rails app with `Capistrano`. While deploying it asks for the `passphrase for key '/home/gokul/.ssh/id_rsa'` but, I can't able to type the passphrase the characters are visible and not authenticating.

**deploy.rb**

```
# Server
server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

# Repository
set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:gokul/testapp.git'
set :scm_passphrase,  ''

set :application,     'testapp'
set :user,            'gokul'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/APP/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), auth_methods: ['publickey'], keys: %w(~/.ssh/privatekey.pem) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord


## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
set :linked_dirs, %w(tmp/pids)

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

**Deployment Log:**

It is asking for the passphrase but while entering the passphrase it is visible and not authenticating.

```
gokul$ cap production deploy
rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
ruby-2.3.1
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 gokul@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 0.708s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-testapp-gokul.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-testapp-gokul.sh
    ✔ 02 gokul@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 0.706s
00:03 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:gokul/testapp.git HEAD
      01 Enter passphrase for key '/home/gokul/.ssh/id_rsa':
password
a
sde
we
ere
re
e
e
e
^C(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Interrupt: 

Tasks: TOP => deploy:check => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error:
```

I tried setting `pty` as `false` as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23227003/4172728. But this doesn't work for me.

Can anyone help me please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding my local machine public key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the list of access keys in the bitbucket repository settings.

And then, added the `id_rsa` to the `ssh-agent` as below:

```
gokul$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Ref: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html