# SSH connection Windows to CentOS 7 for git

Tags: linux, git, ssh, centos7

I've got the following question, I've installed a server with CentOS 7.  Now I want to use this server for git.

The problem is I can't make an SSH connection to the sever to do this.  I already made keys and I putted the id_rsa key in C:\Users\MYNAME.ssh

I also created an git user on the server and putted the public key in /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

When I want to clone the repository to my server I use the following command:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@IP/domains/optiekruymen.be/public_html/.git
```

The output is

> Cloning into 'public_html'...
>
> Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/MYNAME/.ssh/id_rsa':
>
> git@IP's password:

I don't understand why I still need to give the git password, beceause I want tot use the ssh connection and not the password of the git user.

I generated the key on Centos using ssh-keygen, than i copied using

> cat id_rsa.pub >> /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

to copy the file to the git user user next i downloaded the key to my pc and copied id_rsa to /c/Users/MYNAME/.ssh/id_rsa

Extra output

.ssh file settings

> drwx------ 2 git  git  4096 Feb 13 20:59 .ssh

authorized_keys file settings

> -rw-r--r-- 1 git git  408 Feb 13 20:53 authorized_keys

other debug info

> debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA
>
> SHA256:xUB8U9Mn3EkwzhLXjsBlZU1tJMViEfM/Yit5Kjkv/TA
>
> debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with mic,password

Comment: Your private key is password protected. Maybe that is why?

Comment: thats's not the problem, the problem is the second question for the git user password

Comment: Probably because you are typing the wrong ssh-key passphrase. What happens when you just try to ssh? Does it ask for password of git user?

Comment: when i use a key without password it still asks for the password of the git user

Comment: Then the password-less ssh isn't working. Make sure you have added your key correctly in authorized_keys file.

Comment: You're probably being prompted for a password because the ssh server didn't accept your key. There are several things on the server that could cause this. Please run "ls -la .ssh" for the git user on the server and edit your question to include the output. You could also try to get ssh debugging output from git. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/336907/321059) for some discussion on doing that. Or try running "ssh -vvv git@IP".

Comment: how did you make the key? Can you `ssh -vvv git@IP`? What is output?  What errors are in the server log?

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani If the OP had merely entered the wrong passphrase, ssh would have prompted him to enter it again.

Comment: I updated the info in the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the user git to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

and checking the following configurations

- Home directory on the server should not be writable by others: chmod go-w /home/user
- SSH folder on the server needs 700 permissions: chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
- Authorized_keys file needs 644 permissions: chmod 644 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
- Make sure that user owns the files/folders and not root: chown user:user authorized_keys and chown user:user /home/user/.ssh
- Put the generated public key (from ssh-keygen) in the user's authorized_keys file on the server
- Make sure that user's home directory is set to what you expect it to be and that it contains the correct .ssh folder that you've been modifying. If not, use usermod -d /home/user user to fix the issue
- Finally, restart ssh: service ssh restart
- Then make sure client has the public key and private key files in the local user's .ssh folder and login: ssh user@host.com

Answer (score 0):

This message means that your private key is password-protected (encrypted with a password), before a connection to the remote host can be made, this key needs to be decrypted (by you inputing the password).

The easiest way to solve thi is to [remove the passphrase from the private key.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke)

Comment: No this is wrong, I already entered the keys password, but after that I also need to enter the git user's password. And the last thing is the question...

Answer (score 0):

From this message:

> git@IP's password:

You can see that you are being for the password for the `git` user.
As you mentioned above once you added the user to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` its no longer asking you for password.

---

#### /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

> The /etc/ssh/sshd_config file is the system-wide configuration file for `OpenSSH` which allows you to set options that modify the operation of the daemon.
>
> This file contains keyword-value pairs, one per line, with keywords being case insensitive.