# The ssh key configuration for non-root users in CentOS

Tags: authentication, ssh, centos, rsa

Server's Operation System: CentOS 6.6

I want to make a password-free login for a non-root user, named otheruser.
The steps I processed just below:

I. Generating the public and private key in server:

```
[otheruser@localhost ~]# ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I accept the default setting, and then rename `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`

```
[otheruser@localhost ~/.ssh]# cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
[otheruser@localhost ~/.ssh]# ls -al ~
drwx------  2 otheruser otheruser 4096 May 13 06:50 .ssh
[otheruser@localhost ~/.ssh]# ls -al ~/.ssh
drwx------  2 otheruser otheruser 4096 May 13 06:50 .
drwxrwxr--. 4 otheruser otheruser 4096 May  9 07:23 ..
-rw-------  1 otheruser otheruser  412 May 13 06:50 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 otheruser otheruser 1675 May 13 06:48 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 otheruser otheruser  412 May 13 06:48 id_rsa.pub
```

It can notice that the permission of `/home/otheruser/.ssh` is 700, and the permission of `/home/otheruser/.ssh/authorized_keys` is 600, both belong to uesr `otheruser` and group `otheruser`.

II. Modifying /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Add the configuration:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys
AllowUsers otheruser
```

Reboot the sshd service:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

I copyed the private key from server to my local machine. And the try to ssh to server:

```
ssh -i id_rsa otheruse@192.168.1.101
```

But I received a `Permission denied` prompt:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

And the record in `/var/log/secure` was:

```
May 12 07:07:08 localhost sshd[1230]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.1
May 12 07:07:14 localhost sshd[1231]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/otheruser
```

I have no idea what the problem I have. Can someone help me please QAQ

Comment: Can you follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41135590/4133798?

Comment: @sajib-khan It seems not hit my problem.

Comment: The `getenforce` result in the server is `Disabled`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solve my problem by refering this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385148/8005570

And what I do is change the owner mode of `/home/otheruser`

```
[root@localhost ~] chmod go-w otheruser
```

But I still dont understand the reason cause this problem.

Comment: In sshd, the permisson of user fold should not be write by others?