# Enter ssh key passphrase automatically

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

> ~/.bashrc

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
  # This doesn't work
  echo 'my_passphrase' | eval `ssh-agent -s`
  ssh-add
fi
```

When I run a terminal, I see this error 3 times `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`, and when I try to connect to my remote server through ssh, I'm asked to enter my passphrase.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Generate another key pair without a passphrase

Comment: Can't because adding my new public ssh key to the remote server will take at least three days :/.

Comment: Can you just sftp it to the remote server?

Comment: Yeah I can do that for almost all server except the ldap server unfortunately

Comment: Log into the remote server. Run stfp client on that and connect to your local machine. Surely you can fire up a SFTP server on that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke

Comment: I'd recommend the use of a keychain program that runs when you log in and automatically populates your `ssh-agent`.

Comment: sounds like your agent is either not running or your SSH_AUTH_SOCK is not set.  in my .profile i have  "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/.ssh-socket "  and after that,  i have "ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK"  and it will prompt me for the passphrase for any keys stored in $home/MYID/.ssh .   I would be careful with trying to store your passphrase in a script as it is very insecure