# Running ssh command in Python code doesn't require passphrase

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, pycharm, ssh-keys

I'm encountering weird behaviour. When the following python script runs in PyCharm editor (not via command line)

```
sshCommand = "ssh %s@%s -p %s %s" % user,ip,port,cmd
completedProc = subprocess.run(sshCommand,
                                   shell=True,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   check=True,
                                   universal_newlines=True)
```

no prompt asking for passphrase for private ssh key is popped.

Though, when the same python script is run in command line:

```
python3 script.py
```

The prompt does appear.
Does PyCharm store somewhere the passprase? Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour for running via command line?

Found answers to the second question:

[How to avoid being asked passphrase each time I push to Bitbucket](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket)

[How do I remove the passphrase for the SSH key without having to create a new key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke)

Comment: Have you given PyCharm more permissions than it needs?

Comment: Is that command successful? I believe PyCharm will run it without terminal and therefore ssh will fail to ask for passphrase and fails.

Comment: the command is successful in both cases

Comment: Add `-v` to the `ssh` command-line and show us the output.