# Remove passphrase for private key

Tags: ssh-keys

I am using git and I have setup passphrase for private key. I would like to remove it. I am using `openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out id_rsa_new` Should I enter the passphrase without waiting for any response from the above command or should it raise a response question whether it needs passphrase or not. Because, if I enter the above command and wait, its not responding anything it waits forever. How should the behaviour be?

Answer (score 1):

`git` doesn't use `OpenSSL` keys — `git` uses `ssh` and `ssh` has its own set of tools. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/7976758. You need `ssh-keygen -p`.

Please note the question was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps your situation but I use this command on linux/unix systems.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@email.addr"
```

When it prompts for the passphrase I just hit enter.  This gives me a private and public key without a passphrase.