# Permission denied when running Ansible ad hoc command

Tags: ssh, ansible, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run an Ansible ad hoc command via SSH on a Ubuntu 14 LTS server:

```
ansible all -m ping -u myusername
```

However I get the following error message:

> FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password)

When I try to run the ad command with the flag for asking a password, it works:

```
ansible all -m ping -u myusername --ask-pass

absence.ugent.be | success >> {
"changed": false,
"ping": "pong"
}
```

Does anyone know why the command doesn't work without asking for my password? And how I can solve this?

update: as neuhaus suggested, I tried to remove the pass phrase from my ssh keyfile with:

```
ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

But that didn't fix it. The odd thing is that I can still successfully run

```
ansible all -m ping -u myusername --ask-pass
```

with my old pass phrase, even after creating a new ssh key.

Thanks for your help,
Anthony

Comment: Setup keybased auth for remote host.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2):

Your SSH key is protected by a passphrase. By adding `--ask-pass`, ansible will ask for this passphrase (not your login password).

If you want this to work without having to enter a password, [remove the passphrase from your SSH key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke).

Comment: hi neuhaus, thanks a lot. How can I remove the passphrase from my SSH key?

Comment: Click on the link i just added in my answer. Or next time, use a search engine - it's faster than entering a comment into stackoverflow!

Comment: I removed the passphrase with ssh-keygen -p, but that did not fix it.