# gitlab SSH permission denied public key

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I cannot access to my repo with ssh keys. When I'm trying `git push` to my rep on gitlab it asks passphrase.

My steps from scratch. 
Im going to *~/.ssh/* and `rm` all files inside this folder. Then:

1. Create ssh key `ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -C "mymail@gmail.com" -b 4096`
2. then inside *~/.ssh/* `pbcopy < id_rsa.pub`
3. then in gitlab account profile > settings > ssh keys. I put my key and press **add key** button.
4. then back to terminal and type `ssh gitlab.com` and got

> Enter passphrase for key '/Users/local/.ssh/id_rsa'

If I enter a password it works, but this is not an expected result. How to establish proper ssh connection to gitlab using ssh? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: While creating the public keys using `ssh-keygen`, when prompted for a passphrase, just press enter. Don't provide a passphrase if you don't want to be asked for one. This explains why things work when you enter your passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use a passphrase, you must [add your private key to the ssh-agent](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths) in order to not enter that passphrase every time you will use the SSH URL.

But you can also remove [the passphrase from your *existing* private key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/6309) (with `ssh-keygen -p`).
Nothing needs to change on the GitLab side (where your public key is safely registered to your account)