# Change a SSH private Key to an existing one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I had to make a factory reset to my Mac and now I'm configuring again all the development stuff I need like Ruby/Rails etc...

Next step is to configure git and my question is about my ssh key:

From my previous configuration I saved my private ssh key in a text file (I don't know if it was a good idea in terms of security but that's not the point), just copied it from my terminal and pasted it on a text file.

I would like to use that private ssh key again instead of creating a new public and private one. How can I do that? Do I have to create a new one and then replace it somehow for the one I saved time ago? if so, how?

If you can be very specific in your answer it would be very appreciated since this topic is not familiar to me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

## Warning!!!

Reusing private key is **almost always** a bad idea. In your specific case it *may* be reasonable, but for other users, who may see this answer, regenerating a new pair of keys will usually be a better option

## Keys location

By default, ssh keys are stored under `~/.ssh` (hidden by default). Create this directory, if needed. Then you can place your saved private key there, naming it something like `id_rsa`. Since you mention, that you're not very common with this subject, I suppose you ran simple `ssh-keygen` to get this key without extra-options and got a key named like this by default.

After this step change copied file owner to be your user (can be achieved with `chown <your username> <private key file>`) and change permissions to 600 (with `chmod 600 <private key file>`)

As @DeepakMahakale mentioned, after this operation, you may need to execute `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to add your key to the list of keys known by your system.

## Regenerating your public key

It's possible, that you'll need to get public key once again from your private key.  To do so, just run `ssh-keygen`, providing existing private key, like this:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Where `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is a path to private key and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is a path to public key, that will be generated

Comment: This won't help as the public keys is associated with lots of other places.
For example github accounts, ssh access with some servers.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Correct me, if I'm wrong, but to connect to a remote server, you don't need a public key. Having only private will suffice. Hence, Copying saved key under `~/.ssh/` would be enough to connect to GitLab, etc. I added section about regenerating public key only in case author needs that in the future. E.g. to add this new key to a new ssh server.

Comment: Does this create the same public key? I remember in past I have to give my new public key to devops to grant me the ssh access to our private servers so they can add it in `authorized_keys`

Comment: It may not generate exactly same key, but it won't invalidate previous ones, author already used on remote servers. This way, if author has GitLab account with previous pubkey, he/she will still be able to use it. But if author decides to create, say, GitHub account he/she will simply regenerate pubkey and use it there

Answer (score 3):

You can just copy the existing keys in your `.ssh` folder.

If you do not have the folder create one with

```sh
mkdir ~/.ssh
```

Copy the files (these maybe `id_rsa` so check the names before this)

```sh
mv path_to_your_existing/id_ed25519 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
mv path_to_your_existing/id_ed25519.pub ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

**Note:**

you may need to do this

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/<private_key_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a location of:
`C:\Users\User\ssh\authorized_keys`
To place your saved key into?

The only I have encountered personally, I had to open this file "Authorized keys" with WordPad++ then adding the key in.

If this doesn't work see here: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke?rq=1)