# How to setup the git bash that I do not have to type the passpharse for ssh after reboot?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, windows-11

I have set up the ssh key for my laptop following the GitHub docs. Then I was having trouble pushing or pulling because I had to write the passphrase every time. So, I followed this [GitHub doc](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases). Added the below code to my .bash_profile

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2=agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

Now I have to write the GitHub pass every time I turn on my computer. Is there any way so that I do not have to write that passphrase every time I reboot?

Comment: Regenerate a SSH key that doesn't have a passphrase... (That is, leave blank while asking for it during generating.)

Comment: @GenoChen It Worked! Thanks

Comment: @JoyKarmoker Sure, that would bypass completely your issue. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [`man ssh-add`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add), you can try and set `SSH_ASKPASS`, as [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235394/7490).
Replace in your script `ssh-add` with:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa | SSH_ASKPASS=~/.print_ssh_password ssh-add -
```

This assume you have stored your private key passphrase in `%USERPROFILE%\.print_ssh_password`, which is not ideal, but at least protected in your own Windows profile folder.

The other approach, of course, is to [remove the passphrase of your current existing private key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052425/6309) (equally not ideal).
Then no more `ssh-add`.

---

The other obvious option is not have a passphrase in the first place when generating your private key.

You can also remove a [passphrase to an existing private key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/6309).