Running rsync without manually entering passphase/password?
Simply put, this works fine from my bash shell..
rsync -aP --append remote_pc:/tmp/data_file_000000.h5 /tmp -e 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa'

..If I enter my passphrase (or use SSH agent)
I'm trying to do this without needing to manually enter a passphrase or password.
I've got a Python programme to handle archiving files from different remote PCs onto the local PC. Ultimately this will run as a service through supervisor (http://supervisord.org/) in an environment without NFS mounted home directories.
My circumstances:

NFS mounted home directories, same user on both systems
But data files can be huge, and do not reside in home directories
I have confirmed my id_rsa.pub public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) is listed in my authorised keys (~/.ssh/authorized_keys)
In my bash shell, I'm always asked to input my passphrase for any rsync or ssh interaction (unless I of course run ssh-agent and ssh-add)
I've verified that my public/private keys are fine, as SSH'ing/rsync work fine if I provide password or enter pass phase
I do not have sudo privileges, and sending unencrypted passwords are not an option
EDIT: Same user on remote/local PC

I've tried

Good itemised explanation for setting things up here: https://superuser.com/a/555800
Related to that, I've also read the linked https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/rsync-over-ssh-without-password/, but despite following the steps still asked to enter passphrase
Also related, in more detailed steps: SSH/SCP without entering password, https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/
Similar problem being solved with "my_key.pem" (they seem to be for validating SSL certificates..?), not sure that's a solution for me:
Python Subprocess, using rsync with ssh key file, error with method Call
I see information regarding password files (~/.password) and ~/.ssh/config/ but I do not have either on my system

Python 3.10, Ubuntu 22.04.5 but also seems to be an issue on CentOS so not Ubuntu specific.

Use SSH-keys without a passphrase set?

Thank you, while that does work - that feels like a security vulnerability (Removing an existing passphrase: https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/2903608)

It's all about the attack surface - storing the password so that it's available to decode the key somewhere (in a configuration file, etc.) would effectively be the same - just with a step extra. The ssh daemon has to be provided with the passphrase somehow, and if you don't want use the suggested way to run a daemon to provide it (with ssh-agent), I'm not sure what the difference in requirements would be (having a signed certificate would be the same as having the private key).

I confess I do not fully understand SSH keys. I was hoping something equivalent to providing my key would be sufficient (the remote PC already knows my public key). Something like https://github.com/gchamon/sysrsync (See "Private key"), but that still requires a(n empty) passphrase?

@PhilPhil There's an inherent conflict here, because if the script has what's needed to ssh into the remote PC, then an attacker with access to the same resources the script has (whether that's key files, stored passwords, whatever) would also be able to do the same thing. One thing you can do is limit what access an attacker would have by adding a command= option in the remote PC's authorized_keys entry, so the key can only be used for rsync (see this). But that's not really much of a linit...

@PhilPhil Yes, it's sufficient - the public key validates that you have the private key. The issue is that the passphrase is what encrypts the private key, and without the passphrase SSH (or anyone else) can't decrypt the key to prove to the other server that it possesses the private key. So either you have to provide the passphrase so ssh can decrypt it (through ssh-agent or some other mean), or you use a key without a passphrase (as the passphrase would be available regardless). The passphrase protects the key if the key leaks by itself, without other limitations on the use of the key.
